# AngularJS wrapper for extjs4 application - good design?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extjs4, angularjs-routing

I am loading an extjs4(.2.1) application within a div in JSP page. In my JSP i display various links based on what the user is allowed to do. On click of each link the page refreshes and I set some javascript variables (based on server-side logic) which are used by the extjs app as input.

In order to get rid of the page refreshes and therefore improve performance I have refactored this page using AngularJS(I just learnt Angular so I thought I would try using it). I have used routing. So now I get all the inputs for each of the menu clicks at once on page load. When the user clicks on a link the Angular route sets up the appropriate inputs for the extjs application without refreshing the page or going to the server. The extjs application now is present in an IFrame instead of a div as before so the Angular route basically refreshes the IFrame each time a link is clicked to reload the extjs app.

The results seem good. Pages load faster.

My questions :

- Is this good design?
- I know AngularJs's real power is in data binding and directives which I do not leverage. Is it an overkill to use AngularJs for this usecase?
- Is there a better suited library for this specific purpose?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

While it may work, other people maintaining the app need to understand the two frameworks and visitors to your site will have to download all that extra code.

It looks like EXTJS 4 has extensions for UI routing [ext-ux-router](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-router) and ExtJS 5 has it built in.

By using a router built into EXT JS you may be able to avoid the iframe reloading hack.

Comment: thanks for your answer. On the topic of multiple frameworks, as such I do not expect the Angular part of the app to change as the meat of the app is in ExtJs. But I get your point. The router library that you've mentioned looks interesting. The only issue with that is that the menus I've mentioned are the top level Menus of the site. I am not sure whether I can make the ExtJS based menu visually merge into the Site's theme.